# $object->fill(post()) not working with blank date inputs in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, octobercms

I've got a form that includes some date-type inputs:

```
<input name="some_date" type="date" />
```

These fields are not required and may be left unchanged, so the `some_date` field is set up as "nullable" in the database. Here is the line from the migration file in `plugins/acme/plugin/updates/`:

```
$table->date('some_date')->nullable();
```

The issue is that when I attempt to save the form data using Eloquent's `fill()` method and OctoberCMS's `post()` helper I get SQL telling me that I have an "Incorrect date value:''".

```
$object = new SomeObject();
$object->fill(post());
$object->save();
```

Of course, I know an empty string is an invalid format but shouldn't doing this work? Should `post()` not be taking care of this? Or is there an additional setting/var I need to be passing in?

Otherwise I will just need to loop through `post()` and deal with the empty stings myself. A bit messy.

Comment: is `array_filter(post())` helpful ? it will remove the empty strings elements so some_date will have a null value

Comment: @RajaKhoury Oh that's a much neater solution, of course. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Check my answer below, i think using `array_filter()` is not always a good idea unless you're 100% sure about the possible attributes values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought, using `array_filter()` is not a good idea.

What if your model has attributes with falsy values like `is_active = false` ?

```
$data = post();

if(is_array($data) && count($data)){

    $data = array_filter($data);
    $object = new SomeObject();
    $object->fill($data);
    $object->save();

}

// $data  = [
//    'some_date' => ''       // false
//    'is_active' => false   // Will be filtered out
// ];
```

Betters ways i could think of ;

Use the [Nullable Trait](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#nullable) in your model :

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Nullable;

    protected $nullable = ['some_date'];
}
```

Now if `some_date = ''` then it will be nullified.

**Or**

Use the `beforeValidate()`, `beforeSave()` model events and check if `some_date` is an empty string and set it manually to `NULL`

```
public function beforeValidate()
{

    if(empty($this->some_date)){

        $this->some_date = null;

    }

}
```

**Or**

Define a [Mutator](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/mutators#date-mutators) method in your model and manipulate the attribute's value :

```
protected $dates = ['some_date'];

public function setSomeDateAttribute($value)
{

    if(empty($value)){
        $this->attributes['some_date'] = null;
    }  else  {
        $this->attributes['some_date'] = $value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Aaaah the Nullable trait! I've gone with that, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your extensive answer mate.